# App closing when getting on-screen notification(Call Duration, Quick Reply) or Call

Tags: android, android-activity

I Have been working on a basic app, and I have been facing a weird problem. Whenever I get notifications like this and I press the OK button, the app closes. Any Idea why this is happening?

[image]

I Would Have uploaded the code, but its quite long. This also problem happens In Quick Reply SMS and even while getting a call. The app just closes.(PS-Not Force Close).

Comment: i suspect the problem lies between `<activity` and `</activity>` in your manifest.

Comment: This is what I have in the Manifest-                         <activity
            android:name="com.sucho.calculate.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
         android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Thank You so so much @j__m . It was due to **android:noHistory="true"**. Removed it, and working like a charm!

Comment: i'm going to go ahead and add that as an answer so this question no longer appears in the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `android:noHistory="true"` from your `<activity>` definition in your manifest.